# How to associate with an EA-N66 (in repeater mode) in Debian Wheezy?

Tags: debian, wifi

I bought an [Asus EA-N66](http://www.asus.com/Networking/EAN66/) that I want to use in repeater mode to extend the range of my 2.4 GHz wireless network. The setup guide allowed me to associate it to the correct SSID without a hitch, and I configured it (as per Asus' instructions) with a different SSID (but the same network passphrase) to be able to select one of the two networks depending on which one provides the best signal strength.

However, I can't seem to get Debian Wheezy to associate with the EA-N66.

`iwlist scan` shows it being there, along with my non-repeated wireless network. With the following in `/etc/network/interfaces`, the system connects to the regular wireless network:

```
auto wlan3
iface wlan3 inet dhcp
    wpa-psk <long hex string>
    wpa-ssid MySSID
    wpa-proto RSN
```

However, if I change it to the following

```
auto wlan3
iface wlan3 inet dhcp
    wpa-psk <same long hex string>
    wpa-ssid MyRepeaterSSID
    wpa-proto RSN
```

then it doesn't seem to want to associate when I do `/etc/init.d/network stop` followed by `start` (indicated by not receiving any DHCP replies). Digging around I came across a [wireless security how-to](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=318539) on UbuntuForums, which has some specific suggestions. Based on it, instead I tried:

```
auto wlan3
iface wlan3 inet dhcp
    wpa-psk <still same long hex string>
    wpa-ssid MyRepeaterSSID
    wpa-proto RSN WPA
    wpa-pairwise CCIP TKIP
    wpa-group CCIP TKIP
    wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK
    wpa-ap-scan 1
```

but the system still doesn't seem to want to associate (still no DHCP replies).

What further settings do I need to change? **How do I make use of the EA-N66 in repeater mode with Debian Wheezy?** Preferably with a minimum of changes between the regular and the repeated networks while still able to actively pick one over the other.

Just in case it matters, the network card is an Atheros AR9287-based TP-LINK TL-WN881ND, run by the `ath9k` kernel module.

Comment: Can you connect to it using a different OS or device? Does it have some sort of MAC address filter or something?

Comment: @terdon I doubt it has MAC filtering turned on by default (that would make it rather not-easy-to-use), and as for other OS, unfrotunately the only other OS I have readily available is virtualized on the host that can't associate so it doesn't really help.

Comment: I was just thinking of a shitty router I had once that required me to press a button to allow new devices to connect.

Comment: @terdon The EA-N66 does offer WPS, but that is primarily intended for when it is being used in "Ethernet adapter" mode (basically a wired-to-wireless converter). There's also absolutely no mention that I saw of anything like that in the web-based setup wizard.

Comment: @terdon *Network* communication works great; I'm using the wireless network right now to post this comment. It's just the repeater I can't seem to associate with, so based on the fact that `iwlist scan` shows both, I'm *guessing* there's some setting somewhere that needs to be changed that I'm just forgetting about.

Comment: @terdon It was even simpler than that. The PSK is a function of the passphrase *and* the SSID. Change the SSID and keep the passphrase: change the PSK. Simple as that.

Comment: Huh, good catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be really simple. The `<long hex string>` referenced in the `wpa-psk` stanza is dependent on not only the passphrase, *but also the SSID*. Since the SSID was different, it didn't help that the user-supplied network passphrase was identical; the PSK was still different.

Re-running `wpa_passphrase` with the correct SSID and using the generated WPA PSK value allowed me to establish communications through the repeater. It is now working exactly as advertised.